# Missing Template Error When using render :show with Active Model Serializer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, active-model-serializers

I have Active Model Serializer setup and I have the create action to render show on successful creation of the record. If I go directly to a record by URL (/xyz/1) then it renders just fine using AMS. However when using the render method I get the following error:

```
ctionView::MissingTemplate at /contracts.json
==============================================

> Missing template v1/contracts/show, v1/base/show, base/show, application/show with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:json], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby]}. Searched in:
```

I have a feeling if I create a show.erb.json file then the message will go away but then Active Model serializer will not be used.

Here is the line with that is causing the error:

```
render :show, status: :created, location: get_resource
```

If the get_resource method is needed please let me know.

Comment: are your trying to output/render a `json`?

Comment: if yes simply.. do `render :json => obj , status: :created, location: get_resource` here obj can be a any object that can be converted to json.. the problem is when you simply call render and pass it a symbol or a string it tries to search that template in the view folder.. and renders it.. to override this you need to tell the `render` call to render out a plan `json` , `html`, `xml` or what ever.. so it doesn't go on looking for a template to compile and render..

Comment: You are telling Rails to render the view for :show, so it goes looking for show.json